# Basic questions on capacitors

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

after reading some textbooks I realize that I do not understand how a capacitor physically works, I only understood it mathematically. Hence I would like to discuss with you the internal mechanism of a capacitor.

1. Let's consider a simple capacitor. The fundamental equation of this capacitor is \$Q = C.V\$ where **Q** is the stored charge, **C** the capacitance and **V** the voltage. From this we can derive the equation \$i = C.\frac{dV}{dt}\$.

When we apply a voltage **V** accross the capacitor, a current will flow, charging the capacitor. Electrons will accumulate on the negative plate, pushing out the electrons on the other plate. Hence one plate will show some given charge **+q** while the other plate will show the opposite charge **-q**.

What I do not understand is that the capacitor is then electrically neutral, it possess an overall charge **Q = +q + -q = 0**, so according to the equation **Q = C.V**, its voltage should be **0**. What really happens?

Is it possible to have different charges on the plates, or do we always have opposite charges **+q** and **-q**? For example is it possible to have **+1 Coulombs** on one plate and **-2 Coulombs** on the other plate?

2. The energy stored in a capacitor is **1/2 . C . V²**. There is something I do not totally understand in the proof.

We have \$P = V.i = C.V.\frac{dV}{dt}\$. Let's consider that we charge a capacitor to a voltage **Vf**. The energy gained by the capacitor during this charge is
\$\int_0^t{P.dt} = \int_{0}^{Vf}{C.V.dV} = 1/2.C.{V_f}^2\$. However this is the energy gained during the charge, this is not the total of energy **E** stored in the capacitor but the \$ \Delta E\$ brought by the charge. What is the reason we can assume that it is the total energy stored in the capacitor?

3. Let's consider two charged capacitors. At **t = 0**, we connect the two capacitors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmMQSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At **t = 0**, we force both capacitors to have the same voltage. Hence some current will flow in order to equilibrate the charges, according to the following rule: \$ \frac{Q1}{C1} = \frac{Q2}{C2}\$. But we have \$ Q1 + Q2 = Q1(0) + Q2(0) = C1.V1(0) + C2.V2(0)\$.
From the first equation we have \$ Q1 = \frac{C1}{C2} Q2\$. Then the second equation becomes: \$ V_f = V1 = V2 = \frac{C1}{C1 + C2} V1(0) + \frac{C2}{C1 + C2} V2(0)\$. This is the equation giving the final voltage after the switch closes.

Let's consider a similar but different problem: this time we initially charge one capacitor, then we add in series another uncharged capacitor but we keep the voltage source connected:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwkmwL.png)</sup>

What will happen in this case? Because **C1** is already charged to the voltage source, it seems that nothing will happen, all the voltage given by the source will remain accross **C1** and **C2** will never charge, no current will ever flow. However, we know that two capacitors in series are equivalent to another capacitor, hence we should have the same (opposite) charges on the positive plate of **C1** and the negative plate of **C2**. So it seems that current would flow. Besides that, what will happen on the negative plate of **C1** and the positive plate of **C2** who are connected by a wire?

4. Last example, imagine we connect an initially charged capacitor **C1** to an uncharged capacitor **C2**, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frnTOD.png)</sup>

What will happen then? As the circuit is not closed, it seems that no current can flow and hence the capacitor **C1** will remain fully charged and the capacitor **C2** will remain totally uncharged.
However, when we want to prove that this circuit is equivalent to a capacitor of value \$ \frac{C1.C2}{C1 + C2}\$, we say that both capacitors, because they are connected in serie, possess the same charge. From this fact, it seems that some current will flow in order to equilibrate charges on the two capacitors. What will really happen in this case?

By the way, if we consider the following fact " both capacitors, because they are connected in serie, possess the same charge" and the fact that a capacitor possess a charge **+q** on a plate and **-q** on the other plate, it implies the following scheme:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fobaSe.png)</sup>

But what really happens at point **B**? Would we still have **+q** and **-q** on the two connected plates or will the electrons on the **-q** plate join the other plates, leaving two electrically neutral plates?

I hope this huge mess will be readable, thank you for your help.

Comment: Plates do not store charges they conduct with 0V. All the charge is distributed evenly between the conductors as Q with a voltage between them.  However the electrodes interface to the edge of the charge distribution to allow conduction.  Electrodes have C=0 and V=0 along the entire conductor thus Q=0. It’s in between.

Comment: Perhaps the insight you're missing is that the energy is not stored in the charge, it's stored in the electric field between the plates.

Comment: Wheatley, that was tl;dr -- instead, I just let my mind wander a bit as you unrolled your thoughts. Let me complicate things. Suppose you have a charged capacitor (I'll ignore your "capacitor is still neutral despite being charged" point.) And now you set it rotating such that the (+) and (-) ends lay flat on the x-y plane and the rotation is the z-axis. A rotating dipole which *must* radiate power and therefore lose energy. Yes? Now, what you as the observer now instead also go into rotation so that the capacitor no longer appears to rotate? Does it radiate in your new frame of reference?

Comment: Too long - you need to focus this down to one of the four. Then step and repeat.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 : Thank you for your answer but I am not sure to completely understand what you mean. I understand that the wires do not store charges, but I do not see what it implies on the behavior of the circuits?

Comment: @KyleB: yes you're right, It was confused in my mind on this point. Now it is more clear, thank you.

Comment: @jonk: I see what you mean, it seems that my confusion is the result of a wrong point of view. However, I do not see where I should change my point of view when analyzing these circuits?

Comment: Charges are stored inside on the dielectric with maximum charge next to +- electrodes that collect the charge as a single capacitor C=QV.  for electrolytics there is a double electric charge layer effect.  Look it up. The ones with the highest density are called this. It is like two caps in parallel each with different series resistance so after brief short one with highest RC=T charges it’s charge and the cap restores some voltage like memory.

Comment: @Wheatley What I was trying to do, by completely changing up the circumstances as well as your very question itself, was to push you towards a more broadly encompassing view of the whole idea of capacitance. For that, you'll need to better understand electric fields, simplifying dipole concepts, and path integrals. A good physics book that covers this subject would be Chabay and Sherwood's "Matter & Interactions" -- either 3rd or 4th edition. But your questions also touch on other topics related to energy (fundamental) and momentum, we well. So a good physics foundation helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just because a capacitor is overall neutral does not mean it cannot contain a voltage between its two ends. Every capacitor will have +Q charge somewhere and -Q charge somewhere else, and because those charges are not in the same place, we say the capacitor stores the charge Q. Q does not denote the overall charge of the capacitor.
   The magnitudes of the charges in the two plates must be the same because capacitor originally have zero overall charge, and the law of conservation of charge tells us charges cannot be created or destroyed, so the charges on the two plates must be values that cancel each other (+Q and -Q).
2. Before the capacitor is charged, there could not be energy in it. If there was energy in capacitor before charging, the energy must be electric potential energy (the type of energy capacitors would hold), meaning there must be a potential difference in the two plates, meaning that there must be a voltage between two plates. Yet this cannot happen if the capacitor is not charged. There are also other proofs of the same formula for a parallel plate capacitor, such as that involving electric field.
3. Your analysis of the first image is correct. For the second image, the voltage of c1 will change at t=0, as the voltage for C1 originally is now the voltage for C1 and C2 combined. The bottom plate of C1 and top plate of C2 are connected by wire, and as one is charged but the other is not, charges will flow from one to the other. Your second analysis about equivalent capacitor is correct.
4. Same as 3. The two will form an equilibrium (charges flow between capacitors) that makes it effectively behave like one capacitor. You will have two electrically neutral plates in the middle.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Point 1) and 2) are clear to me now.

Comment: Point 3), what are the equations for calculating the final voltages accross C1 and C2?

Comment: Point 4): I do not get it, where current will flow?